# Submitting iOS app using beta version of xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, app-store

My iOS app is nearly complete, but I read about swift's performance improvements in xcode 6.3 and wanted to take advantage.  If I use the latest xcode but compile my app for iOS 8.1 (publicly available) will I have any problems submitting my app?

Comment: If you use a beta version of Xcode you cannot submit it for the App Store.

Comment: Well I would like to know too since Apple posted this articles on its developer site: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=02092015c
Does it mean we can build and submit apps from Xcode 6.3 beta to iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

App needs to be compiled with **release version of Xcode**.

I was already using Xcode 6.3 Beta, and it doesn't let me submit to the Appstore.

[image: AppLoader Screenshot]

I would not recommend using the beta version of Xcode if you plan to release your app soon.

EDIT: You should also be able to use the GM or RC version.

Comment: It's worth noting that you are able to submit to the App Store using a non-release, GM (golden master) version. 

I have a situation where my XCode version is 8.0 (the latest non-development release), but my iPhone is iOS 10.1.  Because of the other answers on this question, I thought I could build my app on my iPhone using a beta version of XCode, but not submit to the App Store.  That's technically true, but I was unaware a GM version of XCode will allow both.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/download/ "Xcode 8.1 GM seed may be used to submit apps to the App Store".

Comment: @Paul, For the "Xcode 9 GM seed", there isn't the message that was for "Xcode 8.1 GM seed", any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

I won't swear to this time, but in the past Apple has always required that submissions be compiled wit the most recent released (not beta) tool chain

The only exceptions have been to allow an older tool chain to be used for a brief period after a release (a few months) and to allow a beta tool chain to be used for early submissions aimed at major new iOS releases(7.0, 8.0, not 8.1)