# can't export ipa file : " Your account already has a valid Certificate"

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-watch

I have an app that also has a Watchkit target. Everything runs fine on device & simulator (for the watch).

I can compile & run, and Archive.
But when I extract, I get an error saying that my account already has a valid iOS Distribution Certificate.

I need to export now for Enterprise Distribution and (with another team) for AppStore distribution.

I also have other apps running with this Distribution Certificate on Enterprise Distribution.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? If I have a valid certificate I should be all good, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today it's not possible to submit apps with WatchKit for AppStore distribution.

First of all Apple is not accepting them yet.
Secondly, it's not possible to submit app with Beta version of Xcode. And you can run Watch apps only in Xcode Beta.

Comment: Do you have any official link to this information? Also, what do you suggest I do with my watchkit extension then? Should I just delete it ?!

Comment: Refer to first answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443583/submitting-ios-app-using-beta-version-of-xcode,
there is screenshot from Xcode there I hope this is "official enough" for you :)

I suggest to: branch your current work with WatchKit, switch to master, remove Watchkit and submit master.

Or:

remove WatchKit, branch it, submit this branch and switch to master for development (with WatchKit). I think this option is better, but maybe first one also fits you.