# Xcode Beta 7.3 When Upload to App Store clicked in Organiser, development teams greyed out

Tags: xcode, app-store, beta

I want to upload my app to release a test flight version. I believe it is allowed to upload using beta Xcode's for Test Flight.

However after I've done the Archive and go to Organiser, when selecting the Upload to Appstore button, the popup with the dropdown with my Development teams, shows all my teams but they are greyed out.

The only team it does show is one where the development and distribution certificates have different names, and it allows me to select the distribution one. I didn't set up this account so not sure what was done differently that lets me select that one and none of the others.

Is this due to the beta Xcode? I'm also running beta OS 10.11.4. I thought we can still upload and release to test flight.

Comment: Did you try with AppLoader?

Comment: yes it won't work because it turns out  we can't upload build on either beta OS or beta Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Apps must be sent to the App Store using a final version of Xcode (the one you download from the Mac App Store). Sending apps with Xcode Beta is not allowed by Apple.

Refer to this answer about Xcode 6.3 Beta: [Submitting iOS app using beta version of xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443583/submitting-ios-app-using-beta-version-of-xcode)