# Can I submit iOS 10 app for review before iOS 10 comes out?

Tags: xcode, app-store, ios10

I would like to have my app released on the app store the day iOS 10 comes out. Is it possible to have it reviewed for submission before iOS 10 is released?

Thanks

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443583/submitting-ios-app-using-beta-version-of-xcode you cannot.

Comment: Paid developers typically get the gold master version of Xcode and iOS a week or so before the public. Submit your app during that time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

However, you must wait for the **GM** (Golden Master) version of Xcode 8 in order to do that.

You can't submit an app via Xcode betas (try to upload an archive: it won't let you).

This GM version is released a bit before the new *public/official*  Xcode release.

It will be available at the usual [Xcode Download Page](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).

Source: [Xcode Support](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/)