# Submitting iPadOS 15 Updates Before Public Release

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipados, wwdc

Right when iPadOS 15 is released in the Fall, I'll want to support the new large widget and a few of the other iPadOS 15 specific features.

**I'm working on them now in the Xcode 13 Beta, but to give these features out to users on launch day, can I update my app now with these features from the Xcode 13 Beta? Or would I need to wait until Xcode 13 is public?**

Sorry if this question seems simple. This is my first time launching on the new update's release day, so I am unsure if I can submit those new features now or wait until launch day.

Please let me know!

P.S. My app is multi-platform (iOS, iPadOS, and macOS). Would submitting early from an Xcode beta potentially mess up the other platforms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submitting iOS app using beta version of xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443583/submitting-ios-app-using-beta-version-of-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to wait until Xcode 13 and iOS 15 are publicly released, or at least until Apple releases the RC (Release Candidate). Beta versions of Xcode cannot push builds but releases and RCs can.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response!